# RESTful jersey the requested resource is not available

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, tomcat8

I am developing a REST web service which should be able to respond with a XML depending on the URL params. I had a first version of this application as local thus I had a POJO main class that initialized the XML processing. The problem is that the resources are unable to be located, and maybe I have done a mistake put the POJO main method inside the Application class. This **URI** is working localhost:8090/org.CTAG.DATEX2REST, but if you add the location URL path it does not work.

**PD: I am using jersey framework, maven, JAXB and Tomcat8**

**EDITED:** I have removed Application class, and the POJO main now is a ServletContextListener

**Rest class**:

```
package com.CTAG.rest;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.CTAG.core.Traslator;
import eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.D2LogicalModel;
import eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.Situation;
import eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.SituationPublication;
import com.CTAG.filters.FilterByRoad;
@Path("/datex")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class DataExchange {

    private D2LogicalModel datex2 = Traslator.d2;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response getDatex() {

        return Response.ok(this.datex2).build();

    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{road}")
    public Response getDatexByRoad(@PathParam("road") String roadName){

        SituationPublication payLoad = (SituationPublication)this.datex2.getPayloadPublication();
        FilterByRoad filter = new FilterByRoad(payLoad.getSituation());
        List<Situation> filteredList = new LinkedList<>();
        filteredList.addAll(filter.filterByRoad(roadName));
        payLoad.setSituation(filteredList);
        this.datex2.setPayloadPublication(payLoad);

        return Response.ok(this.datex2).build();
    }
}
```

**Application class**:

```
package com.CTAG.application;

import eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.D2LogicalModel;
import eu.datex2.schema._2_0._2_3.SituationRecord;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;

import com.CTAG.core.Traslator;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 * Configuration of the REST application. This class includes the resources and
 * configuration parameter used in the REST API of the application.
 *
 * @author Andoni Da Silva
 *
 */

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class ExchangeApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return Stream.of(D2LogicalModel.class)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    //Old POJO main method
    public static void init() throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            Map<SituationRecord, Integer> map = new HashMap<> ();
            while (true) {

                URL url = new URL (" http://infocar.dgt.es/datex2/dgt/SituationPublication/all/content.xml");
                Map<SituationRecord, Integer> copia = map;
                map = Traslator.traslator (copia, url);
                sleep (120000);
                //Preubassleep(30000);
            }
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException | JAXBException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace ();

        }
    }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>CTAG DATEX2</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.CTAG.DATEX2REST</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems your have you servlet mapping is wrong, should be something like follows, you, you need to tell the servlet where to pick the annotated classes from

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.CTAG.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It could be part of the problem, but it does not solve the problem, thank you.

Comment: what is url that you are trying ?

Comment: localhost:8090/org.CTAG.DATEX2REST/rest/datex

Comment: btw, why are you using Application class as well as servlet. I suppose only one of it. Not both

Comment: Could you explain that please? I am new with RESTful and ws

Comment: @datex2 if you implementing application interface class servlet is not needed. @ Applicationpath will. Please check here it is neatly explained

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Auto scan REST service (false in case resteasy.resources is given ) -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.rest.service.HelloWorldService</param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- <listener> <listener-class> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap 
    </listener-class> </listener> -->

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What is this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, it was that I had the web.xml in the wrong directory, and it has to be in WebContent/WEB_INF/web.xml thus it was being ignored due to de fact that mvn didn`t fail if web.xml was not reached. Moreover, the POJO main class was replaced by a ServletContextListener and also a Application class was removed.